# Table 'shopping_cart', which contains 2 foreign key as primary key and other foreign key, have an error with relationship while importing data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

While importing data, I have

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb_innodb`.`shopping_cart`, CONSTRAINT `fk_shopping_cart_order_payment1` FOREIGN KEY (`paypal_transaction_id`) REFERENCES `order_payment` (`paypal_transaction_id`))
```

MySQL script for creating 'shopping_cart' and 'order_payment' tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb_innodb`.`order_payment` (
  `paypal_transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `paid_by` VARCHAR(91) NOT NULL,
  `is_paypal_verified` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `is_shipping_address_confirmed` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `total_price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`paypal_transaction_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb_innodb`.`shopping_cart` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `paypal_transaction_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `shop_id`),
  INDEX `fk_shopping_cart_product1_idx` (`product_id` ASC, `shop_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_shopping_cart_order_payment1_idx` (`paypal_transaction_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_shopping_cart_product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id` , `shop_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb_innodb`.`product` (`id` , `shop_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_shopping_cart_order_payment1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`paypal_transaction_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb_innodb`.`order_payment` (`paypal_transaction_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0GQ5.png)

A customer can purchase multiple products from different shops, hence 'order_payment' is created which stores the payment with sum of prices of the products. Table 'order' and 'order_payment' work properly, so I have a suspicion, there is a problem with primary key of 'shopping_cart' table.

Comment: 'so I have a suspicion, there is a problem with primary key of 'shopping_cart' table.' - nope, the error is quite clear you need to create the parent(ie order_payment) before the child(shopping_cart).

Comment: Thank you, I created parent firstly. The problem were with importing data, using 'LOAD DATA INFILE', I had "LINES TERMINATED BY \n" instead of "LINES TERMINATED BY \r\n".

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. But: Put what is needed but only what is needed to ask in your post.

Comment: Did the error come from `CREATE` or from `LOAD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with importing data using `'LOAD DATA INFILE'`, I had `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` instead of `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. The MySQL will find carriage return (`\r`) and line break (`\n`) while importing data.

The full code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'fake_shopping_carts.csv' INTO TABLE shopping_cart
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(product_id, shop_id, paypal_transaction_id);
```